# JavaFX starting application from different class

Tags: java, javafx-8

EDIT: I have fixed this now by making `JavaFxWindow` a public class.
But, when you make a class public it has to exist in its own-named `*.java` source file. Is there a solution for the below where both classes can exist in the same file?

I am trying to start a JavaFX application from a different class. Normally, we start a JavaFX applicaiton with a call to `launch`, from within `Application` class itself.

But what about if I want to make a program that gives the user a choice of either displaying a JavaFX window, or displaying a Swing window.

This is as close as I can get with my feeble understanding:

```
package org.requiredinput.aitoopwj5e;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;

class ch2q17 {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        char userInput;

        System.out.println("Please choose either Swing window [s], " +
                "or JavaFX window [f] ... ");

        JavaFxWindow myWindow = new JavaFxWindow();
        myWindow.main(argv);
        //myWindow.launch(argv);

    }
}

class JavaFxWindow extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Application.launch(argv);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Window");
        //root.getChildren().add(vb);
        System.out.println("Showing stage...");
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

But it throws-up lots of exciting errors:

```
% java -cp bin/test org.requiredinput.aitoopwj5e.ch2q17
Please choose either Swing window [s], or JavaFX window [f] ... 
Exception in Application constructor
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class org.requiredinput.aitoopwj5e.JavaFxWindow
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2/1595428806.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.requiredinput.aitoopwj5e.JavaFxWindow.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$158(LauncherImpl.java:818)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$51/236498957.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$53/991256019.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$55/87321364.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$54/1460563668.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$43/1350641094.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

I am a beginner, and the answer is probably something way over my head involving some obscure arcane occult esoteric Java no doubt, so please try to explain this in a way that someone who's only just learnt what an inner class is can understand...

Comment: Why do you want the classes to be defined in the same file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it an inner static class:

```
public class ch2q17 {

    public static class JavaFxWindow extends Application {

        @Override
        public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
            Group root = new Group();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1024, 768));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Test Window");
            //root.getChildren().add(vb);
            System.out.println("Showing stage...");
            primaryStage.show();
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaFxWindow.main(args);
    }
}
```

Edit: I skipped the part where to choose, which UI to show, as this is about starting the JavaFX app.

Comment: I would ask also, but I don't want to confuse my question: Is it easy to pass arguments to `JavaFxWindow` from `ch2q17` to e.g. set its height?

Comment: You can add arguments to the array that is passed into the call to JavaFxWindow.main(), better said, you need to create a copy of the array to a new one that has the original size plus the arguments you ant to pass in and add your arguments. When calling your main, you don't have a JavaFxWindow object yet, this will be created by that call.

Comment: Whoah. Its gonna take me some time to figure all that out. Thanks. I was going to try overriding the `JavaFxWindow`' constructor, but that will probably break something and stop the application from working.

Answer (score 3):

Just define each of the classes you need in separate files. Note that there is an [overloaded version of `Application.launch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.Class-java.lang.String...-) that takes a parameter representing the class with the `start` method. So you can do:

AppLauncher.java:

```
public class AppLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1 || 
            (! "S".equals(args[0].toUpperCase()) ||
            (! "F".equals(args[0].toUpperCase())) {
            System.out.println("Provide an argument of S for Swing or F for JavaFX");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        if ("S".equals(args[0].toUpperCase())) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() ->
                new SwingApplication().setVisible(true));
        } else {
            Application.launch(FXApplication.class, args);
        }
    }
}
```

SwingApplication.java:

```
public class SwingApplication extends JFrame {
    public SwingApplication() {
        // set up UI etc...
    }
}
```

FXApplication.java:

```
public class FXApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome. +1 for the overloaded method!